# Error: Unknown argument: init @graphql-codegen/cli

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-codegen

I'm following [this](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/installation).

I installed `@graphql-codegen/cli` as a Dev dependency here is my `package.json`.

```json
{

  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.8",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "next": "11.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.1.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.0",
    "graphql-codegen": "^0.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

When i run:

```sh
yarn graphql-codegen init
```

I'm getting this error:

```sh
...
Error: Unknown argument: init
...
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong here!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yes you can run `npx graphql-codegen init` or uninstall `graphql-codegen` and re install it

Comment: `@graphql-codegen/cli` and `graphql-codegen` both supply the `graphql-codegen` binary. If you're getting the above error, you probably don't need `graphql-codegen` installed. Remove it from your `package.json` and reinstall the `node_modules`.